# How to send job artifacts from Gitlab CI to github (unpacked in a directory)

Tags: github, gitlab, continuous-integration, artifacts, artifact

sorry for my ignorance ,I am just new on the topics. I checked deeply but couldn't able to find a way about how can I push my artifacts from gitlab ci/cd and unpack these artifacts and make them exist in a directory in github? Can you help with that please? Thanks in advance